# Keep one of two consecutive chars in a string

Tags: python

So I want to replicate a word `n` times in my function but I want to eliminate the consecutive characters.

For example `repete (amanha, 2) = "amanhamanha"`

My function:

```
def repete(palavra,n):
    
    a = []
    b=""
    
    for n in range (0,n): 
        a.append(palavra)

    b = b.join(a)   

    return b
```

Comment: so what will be your output when word is `aaaaaaaaa` and you need to repeat it 3 times say

Answer (score 1):

The first step is to determine the longest overlap between the start and end of the word.  The next() function can be used to get the number of characters to skip by getting the first match starting from the longest substring down to the shortest and defaulting to zero if there is no overlap.  Then the repetition can be performed on the remaining part of the word (i.e. skipping the length of the common part)

```
def repeat(w,n):
    skip = next((i for i in range(len(w)-1,0,-1) if w[:i]==w[-i:]),0)
    return w + (n-1)*w[skip:]

print(repeat("amanha",2))  # amanhamanha
print(repeat("abc",2))     # abcabc
print(repeat("abcdab",2))  # abcdabcdab
```

You could also use the max() function to get the length to skip (not as efficient as next() but shorter to write):

```
def repeat(w,n):
    skip = max(range(len(w)),key=lambda i:i*(w[:i]==w[-i:]))
    return w + (n-1)*w[skip:]
```